# scroll en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
function scroll() {

  shouldScroll = chat.scrollTop + chat.clientHeight === chat.scrollHeight;
  if (!shouldScroll) {
    scrollToBottom();
  }
}
function scrollToBottom() {
  chat.scrollTop = chat.scrollHeight;
}
scrollToBottom();
setInterval(scroll, 100);
```

El problema es que cuando quiero subir para leer las conversaciones, automaticamente se baja. Entiendo que es po el setInterval pero sin ense no baja automaticamente en mi chat. Como puedo arreglarlo?

Gracias

Comment: Hola Isaac, haces referencia a un setInterval pero en el código que publicaste no hay ninguno, debes especificar cuales es el objetivo de tu consulta, cual es el error y el código que falla sin sesgos como el que te indiqué para que puedas recibir una buena ayuda! Saludos

Comment: @nerdcoder listo. Saludos

Comment: @nerdcoder SetInterval() es una función propia de JavaScript, no necesita ser definida.

Comment: Lo sé, me refería a que no estaba en el código que Isaac escribió para revisar. Falta que indique como funciona su aplicación, que es lo que quiere lograr, que recuerde que ninguno de los que te está leyendo sabe el contexto de su pregunta a menos que lo explique bien. Hay un chat pero no sabemos como está estructurada su aplicación, que eventos hacen que se agregue un mensaje ni nada, un error o un problema debe tener un contexto. Saludos

Comment: Por favor publica el html la estructura, para ayudarte con la solución. Yo sé como ayudarte, pero necesito el html para colaborarte. Que es chat? un objeto del DOM? debes ser mas especifico con tu código para que te demos respuestas que necesites. Gracias!

Comment: Este es mi HTML `<body>

  <div class="chat-column">
    <div id="chat"></div>    
    <br>
    <label for="entrada" class="inputOutline">
      <input id="entrada" class="input responsive-column" autofocus placeholder="Escribe algo" type="text">
    
    </label>
    <div id="link" align="center">
      <br>
    <id="link" href="" ali>Test</li>
    </div>
  
  </div>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>`